# Relationship between capacitance and capacitor voltage rating?

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I recently went to buy a capacitor of 10 microfarad and I was told by the shop that 10microfarad 67 volt is available.

The confusion for me is that will I be able to charge the full 10microfarad only if the potential difference across plates is 67 volt or is 67 volt the maximum voltage it can safely bear or both?

When I searched the web i was getting both answers sort of? All I need to know is if i use this capacitor in 9v circuit, then i get 10microfarad or something like 1-2 microfarad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some capacitors, especially ceramics will derate or have lower capacitance as the applied voltage goes higher. However, most electrolytics will have nearly the same capacitance independent of the applied voltage. The voltage rating is the maximum voltage that should be applied to the capacitor, it does NOT imply that you will only get the rated capacitance when that voltage is applied.

Comment: FYI electrolytic capacitors tend to respond to significant over-voltage by exploding. The jokers in my high school electronics class used to plug under-rated capacitors into the wall and wait for them to pop and startle people.